# Is it possible to "catch" a wireless signal with a second wireless router?

Tags: router, wireless-networking

I've got a modem with a build in wireless router. This sends the signal with good strength trough the entire house.

I was wondering if it is possible to catch this wireless signal in another room with another wireless router, and distribute the signal from there with cables for devices that have no wireless receiver.

So I basically want to distribute the signal with a second wireless router, without having to put up cables throughout the entire house.

Is this setup possible?

Comment: off topic, but just search Amazon for Wifi range extender and get one with at least one ethernet port.

Comment: @Paul Dixon What will he need Ethernet port for?

Comment: to plug the device into his ethernet network perhaps?

Comment: Well, he said he wants wireless repeater without any cabling, hasn't he?

Comment: " was wondering if it is possible to catch this wireless signal in another room with another wireless router, and distribute the signal from there with cables for devices that have no wireless receiver."  @david-jashi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your router must have such functionality in it's firmware. It's either that, or you may try to flash it with [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) or [Robin-Mesh](http://wiki-robin.meshroot.com/Download) firmware, if yours is on compatibility list.

Comment: Thank you that is usefull information. I've got an old wireless router that I'm picking up this afternoon. I think that baby is about 5 years old. What are my chances that it'll support this functionality?

Comment: Well, Linksys WRT series, that this firmware was originally written for is much older. Check compatibility list.